# When using a FragmentManager and replace, hiding a View inside the fragment will cause future FragmentTransactions to show blank

Tags: android, android-fragments

I use `FragmentManager` and `FragmentTransaction` to replace `Fragment`s in and out of the `Activity`.

The problem is, if any of the `Fragment`s changes the visibility of one of its `View`s, any future change of the fragments will result in a blank view.

Why is this happening and how can I solve it?

Comment: Please show your code

Comment: While trying to create a small reproduction of the problem, I got the reason: I called setVisibility() from javascript interface, which is not in the UI thread.
Running it in the UI thread did the trick :)

Comment: Glad to heard. Please post this as answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found the root cause  while trying to reproduce the error in a smaller program: I had changed the UI in a method called from javascript inside the `Webview`. This is a different thread.

When I run it in the UI thread, the problem vanished.